# Using Skype presence control over HTTPS

Tags: https, skype

I would like to create a page, that displays the skype status of logged user like this:

http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/

It works fine on HTTP, but I have to use https protocol.

MyStatus link is a http link that displays the status of user, but browsers do not display this correctly or display a notification because of http link.

Has anyone had experience with this? Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

The solution is you have to create a proxy handler (ashx) file, that catches the webrequest and returns the same content in response.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just get the data yourself and then display whatever you want that indicates their status.

http://mystatus.skype.com/user.xml

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i think if i get the http link over https with javascipt or something, the browsers display the notification for the action like before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this specific secured (HTTPS) domain for Skype widgets:

https://secure.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js